# SQL SERVER for stock market order matching

Tags: sql, if-statement, stored-procedures, cursor

I have three Stock Market App tables:  BIDS, ASKS and TRADES

A new Ask order gets inserted into the ASKS table. Then if NewASK.Price is <= BIDS.Price new row(s) need to be inserted into the TRADES table.

To avoid a cursor I've created a #temptable, seed it with all Bids where `BIDS.Price <= NewASK`.Price and then `INSERT INTO Trades SELECT FROM #temptable WHERE CumulativeNumberOfContracts < NewASK.NumberOfContracts`.

At present I then do another `INSERT INTO Trades SELECT TOP 1 FROM #temptable WHERE CumulativeNumberOfContracts > NewAsk.NumberOfContracts` (i.e. NewAsk.NumberOfContracts = 25 and #temptable contains 3 Bids of 10 Contracts each the first two of which are filled 100% and the third only 50%).

However, I am running into difficulties where NewAsk.NumberContracts <= CumulativeNumberOfContracts and think the only way to handle is via `IF . . . THEN` blocks.

QUESTION:  Am I not getting more complicated than just using a cursor (or WHILE block)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.  I would recommend that you delete this question and ask a new one.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your statements in the question are non-standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I will add a SQL Fiddle example/link as soon as I have the above code "de-bugged".